# Change Label Text according to Table Record

Tags: c#

How can I change this code so the label's text changes. Between this..Controls there was an MdiParent but I don't have one.

```cs
private void KeyOfficial_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label2.Text = "Login as: " + ((Form)this..Controls["label1"]).Text; 
}
```

Comment: Your question is not clear .. you want to change the label2.Text after loading the datatable in c# ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you initialize KeyOfficial you could submit an reference to your main form like this:

```
MainForm MainFormRef;

public KeyOfficial(MainForm mainRef)
{
    this.MainFormRef = mainRef;
}
```

In Main Form you initialize like this:

```
KeyOfficial koForm = new KeyOfficial(this);
```

And the reference is set. 
Now you can reach the lable1:

```
label2.Text = "Login as: " + this.MainFormRef.label1.Text;
```

Comment: the thing is that label1 is not on the same form as label 2. I want to read the value of label 1 to change label 2. Thanks

Comment: On which form is lable2?

Comment: label 2 is on the Key Offical form.. but label 1 is on a Main Form.

Comment: Changed my post. This could be what you want.

Comment: Ok sorry, my fault. It will work without ref, but i think Sumer Singh's post is the better way.

Comment: Nice to hear that this helped you :)

Answer (score 1):

Here you can use this to get the instance of the MainForm whenever you want to access its fields

```
 public static MainForm instance=null;

    public static MainForm GetInstance()
    {

        if (instance != null)
        {
            return instance;
        }
        else
        {
            instance = new MainForm();
            return instance;
        }
    }
```

Place this code in MainForm.cs and then call this function whenever you want to access that field directly like,

```
MainForm.GetInstance().<field_name>
```

I have used the similar things in my app when I need to access different fields from one form to another and its working fine for me.